Why is this soldering iron red hot in the middle section?
As you can see in the picture, my soldering iron is red hot in the lower middle section. I'm confused.
Why is it happening?
This hasn't happened while using other soldering irons.


Check whether the "tip sleeve" can be pushed further to the grip in cold state.

The soldering iron pictured has a removeable tip. The larger diameter section is hollow and is designed to slide onto the heating element. It is usually slotted and fitted with a circular spring to clamp the tip onto the element to provide mechanical security and good thermal contact.

Tip slot and spring clip.
The "iron" has a resistor heating element inside the shaft. It will use regular or thicker wires to prevent heating in the zone closer to the handle to prevent damage to the handle and to only apply power in the zone where required.
The fact that the tip is glowing red-hot indicates that it has inadequate thermal loading. In normal use the tip would provide a heat sink for the element as it has a larger surface area and would dissipate the heat better than the element alone. There would also be some heat dissipated during use.
The fix:

Allow the iron to cool.
Remove the tip and use something as a depth probe to measure how far in the element should go.
Transfer that measurement onto the element measuring from the tip. Use a marker to indicate how far down the element the tip should go.
Reassemble the iron, pushing firmly to insert the element to your mark.
Test.


Opinion on whether a dab of thermal paste would help the tip to heat up better ?

@Criggie, I don't know. I'd be concerned about the temperature rating of the paste. Most semiconductor heatsinking applications would be around 100 - 120°C max, I suspect, whereas the iron might hit 400°C. (It looks like it has already.)

@Transistor Actually, you need some 500 °C or so for a visible red glow. So it's certainly well past 400 °C.

I like this answer because I expected someone to write "That's a cheap toy, throw it out and buy a Pace/Weller/Whatever". This is a far more interesting and practical answer.

@Criggie even high temp pastes are only rated to about 350°C, which is similar to what you want your tip to reach

It looks like the tip isn't fully pushed on, going by the proportions.

@pipe Changing tip shouldn't be anywhere near this complicated. This is some crap brand indeed and it will be cumbersome to work with because of it, possibly dangerous even if you risk burns when changing tip. Not that Pace or Weller are any premium brands either, but they are better for hobby purposes.
